# Why can I assign a value to a reference using array destructuring, but not object destructuring?

Tags: javascript

Using array destructuring I can assign a value to a reference:

```js
const o = {}
;[o['something']] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
console.log(o) // { something: 'a' }
```

But I cannot do the same with object destructuring. Why?

```js
const o = {}
{ ['1']: o['something'] } = { '1': 'a' } // Syntax Error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. The issue is just that the `{ }` is interpreted as *block* here instead of an object literal! For the same reason you can't write `{ a: 1 }.a`.

You can wrap the whole statement in parens to avoid this problem (in the same way as `({ a: 1 }).a` makes the previous example work):

```js
const o = {}
;({ ['1']: o['something'] } = { '1': 'a' })
console.log(o) // { something: 'a' }
```

Answer (score 1):

A variable can be assigned its value with destructuring separate from its declaration using the parentheses `( ... )` around the assignment statement like:

```js
const o = {};
({ ['1']: o['something'] } = { '1': 'a' });

console.log( o )
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring),

> The parentheses `( ... )` around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `const {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> Your `( ... )` expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.